# Is there anyway to make this work without explicit casting? (trying a Generic Parent-Child relationship)

Tags: java, design-patterns, generics

**The Interfaces:**

```
package sandBox.ps.generics.compositePattern;

import java.util.Collection;

interface AnimalInterface {
    String getID();

    /*
     * getAnimals can be:
     * 1. AnimalInterface
     * 2. Anything that implements/extends AnimalInterface (i.e. AnimalInterface or DogInterface)
     */
    Collection<? extends AnimalInterface> getAnimals();
}

interface DogInterface extends AnimalInterface {
    String getBreed();
}
```

**The classes:**

```
package sandBox.ps.generics.compositePattern;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;

class AnimalClass implements AnimalInterface {
    private final String id;
    private final Collection<? extends AnimalInterface> animals;

    AnimalClass(final String id,
        final Collection<? extends AnimalInterface> animals) {
    this.id = id;
    this.animals = animals;
    }

    @Override
    public String getID() {
    return this.id;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends AnimalInterface> getAnimals() {
    return this.animals;
    }
}

class DogClass extends AnimalClass implements DogInterface {

    private final String breed;

    DogClass(final String id, final String breed) {
    super(id, Collections.<AnimalInterface> emptyList());
    this.breed = breed;

    }

    @Override
    public String getBreed() {
    return this.breed;
    }

}
```

**Testing the classes:**

```
package sandBox.ps.generics.compositePattern;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

public class TestClass {
    public void testA() {
    // Dog Collection (Child)
    final DogInterface dog = new DogClass("1", "Poodle");
    final Collection<DogInterface> dogCol = new ArrayList<DogInterface>();
    dogCol.add(dog);

    // Animal Collection of Dogs (Parent)
    final AnimalInterface animal = new AnimalClass("11", dogCol);
    final Collection<AnimalInterface> parent = new ArrayList<AnimalInterface>();
    parent.add(animal);
    // Animal Collection of Animals (Grand-Parent)
    final AnimalInterface grandParent = new AnimalClass("11", parent);

    // Get Dog
    for (final AnimalInterface parents : grandParent.getAnimals()) {
        /* I know the this code would work.
         * My question is, is there anyway to do this without explicit casting
        for (final AnimalInterface child : parents.getAnimals()) {
    if (child instanceof DogInterface) {
        System.out.println(((DogInterface)child).getBreed());
    }
    }
        */

        /*  HERE:   This is the part I am trying to solve.
         *  Do I use extends or super for AnimalInterface
         *  Is there any option such that I don't need to do a casting of some type
         */
        for (final DogInterface child : parents.getAnimals()) {
        System.out.println(child.getBreed());
        }       
    }
    }
}
```

Questions:

1. The last lines of the test class try to access the animals.
2. What I am trying to figure out is that, is there anyway to avoid
   explicit casting?
3. Is there any combination of extends, super or some other generic
   term that would make this work?
4. If casting is the only option where should it be done?
5. I already know this would work:

> ```
> for (final AnimalInterface child : parents.getAnimals()) {
>     if (child instanceof DogInterface) {
>        System.out.println(((DogInterface)child).getBreed());
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid if you want to invoke a subclass method on a superclass reference, then casting is indeed necessary.

That said, I would tackle this a different way but perhaps re-architecting your program so that it isnt necessary at the TestClass level to know what sort of animal you're dealing.

For example, you could do something along the lines of

```
for (final AnimalInterface child : parents.getAnimals()) {
    System.out.println(child.getType()); // or something similar
```

The point being that you could push the responsibility of knowing what to retur is to the actual classes.

Classes where "breed" was the natural answer could return the breed, for others it could return something else.

In this case you may not want every animal to have this method (getType) so you could also perhaps have a hasType (or whatever) first.

Finally, if you find you do at some point really need to determine the actual type in question you could further push that to another class that only does this determination, leaving is so that only 1 class has this knowledge.

I hope this all makes sense - it's a bit of a rambling answer...

Answer (score 2):

You can always use a visitor:

```
DogBreedVisitor dogBreedVisitor = new DogBreedVisitor();
for (final AnimalInterface child : parents.getAnimals()) {
    child.visit(dogBreedVisitor);
}
```

Here is a very simple implementation:

```
interface AnimalInterface {
    void visit(AnimalVisitor visitor);
}

interface DogInterface extends AnimalInterface {
    String getBreed();
}

interface AnimalVisitor {
    public void visit(DogInterface dog);
    public void visit(AnimalInterface animal);
}

class DogBreedVisitor implements AnimalVisitor {
    @Override
    public void visit(DogInterface dog) {
        System.out.println(dog.getBreed());
    }
    @Override
    public void visit(AnimalInterface animal) {
       // ignore
    }
}

class DogClass implements DogInterface {
    @Override
    public String getBreed() {
        return "my breed";
    }
    @Override
    public void visit(AnimalVisitor visitor) {
        visitor.visit(this);
    }
}

class AnimalClass implements AnimalInterface {
    @Override
    public void visit(AnimalVisitor visitor) {
        visitor.visit(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I will read up more on the visitor pattern and give it a try

Comment: I don't believe that this code will work as expected because the `visit` method is determined at compile-time. So the `visit(AnimalInterface)` method will always be called. The `DogBreedVisitor` will need to do type checking.

Comment: @DavidV No, i won't be called, because inside `DogClass`, the compiler knows statically that it should call `visit(DogInterface)` (because `this` is of type `DogClass`).

Comment: There is only one way to find that. Just copy the code and run it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it. You need to give `AnimalInterface` a generic parameter that tells you what types of animals you get from `getAnimals()`, and then you need to use `AnimalInterface<DogInterface>` for `animal` and `AnimalInterface<AnimalInterface<DogInterface>>` for `grandParent`.

The complete code is this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;

interface AnimalInterface<A extends AnimalInterface<?>> {
  String getID();

  /*
   * getAnimals can be:
   * 1. AnimalInterface
   * 2. Anything that implements/extends AnimalInterface (i.e. AnimalInterface or DogInterface)
   */
  Collection<A> getAnimals();
}

interface DogInterface extends AnimalInterface<DogInterface> {
  String getBreed();
}

class AnimalClass<A extends AnimalInterface<?>> implements AnimalInterface<A> {
  private final String id;
  private final Collection<A> animals;

  AnimalClass(final String id, final Collection<A> animals) {
    this.id = id;
    this.animals = animals;
  }

  @Override
  public String getID() {
    return this.id;
  }

  @Override
  public Collection<A> getAnimals() {
    return this.animals;
  }
}

class DogClass extends AnimalClass<DogInterface> implements DogInterface {

  private final String breed;

  DogClass(final String id, final String breed) {
    super(id, Collections.<DogInterface> emptyList());
    this.breed = breed;
  }

  @Override
  public String getBreed() {
    return this.breed;
  }

}

class TestClass {
    public void testA() {
    // Dog Collection (Child)
    final DogInterface dog = new DogClass("1", "Poodle");
    final Collection<DogInterface> dogCol = new ArrayList<DogInterface>();
    dogCol.add(dog);

    // Animal Collection of Dogs (Parent)
    final AnimalInterface<DogInterface> animal = new AnimalClass<DogInterface>("11", dogCol);
    final Collection<AnimalInterface<DogInterface>> parent = new ArrayList<AnimalInterface<DogInterface>>();
    parent.add(animal);
    // Animal Collection of Animals (Grand-Parent)
    final AnimalInterface<AnimalInterface<DogInterface>> grandParent = new AnimalClass<AnimalInterface<DogInterface>>("11", parent);

    // Get Dog
    for (final AnimalInterface<DogInterface> parents : grandParent.getAnimals()) {
      for (final DogInterface child : parents.getAnimals()) {
        System.out.println(child.getBreed());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am expecting multiple levels (maybe 8) of parent-child(which could have more parent/children) relations so I think the assignment "AnimalInterface<AnimalInterface<DogInterface>>" would get very complicated.

Comment: Yes, it quickly gets really really ugly. In this case its probably best to overthink your design. For example, does have `AnimalInterface<AnimalInterface<DogInterface>>` a meaning? Does it have a name that you can give? In this case, write a separate class that represents it (it can even implement `AnimalInterface<AnimalInterface<DogInterface>>` so that all the types work as before, just with shorter type names).